# Android Studio - Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. But Can download by web browser

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, firebase

I am a new bie Android studio. This is great tool to build Android app. But I got some problem with it.
That is : When I add dependencies into build.gradle,
"

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter(){
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

dependencies in app build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'

    /* Firebase SDK */
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'

    /* Firebase UI */
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.2'

    /* For Google Play Services */
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
}
"
```

I got the message 
"

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download jackson-databind.jar (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.2)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.2.2/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.2.2/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar'.
         > peer not authenticated
"
```

But when I paste link 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.2.2/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar' on web browser I can download jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar.
I don't known why android studio 'Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.2.2/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar'.

Could you explain and help me resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. download jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
2. copy it to app/libs
3. click the right mouse button on jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar and choose "Add as library"

finally, you can use jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar in your project.